# How can I delete data from logicblox without warning message

Tags: datalog, logicblox

In the new version of logicblox (any version later than 4.2.1), if there is a predicate "Person(p), hasPNr(p:n) -> int(n)."
And I insert an data "+Person(p),+hasPNr[p]=1."
Then if I want to delete data by "-Person(1)." 
There will be an warning message " WARNING : expression '1' has type 'int', but a value of type 'Person' is needed. The compiler has inserted a use of the predicate 'hasPNr' to allow the code to compile."
How can I delete the data without this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete by:

```
-Person(n) <- Person:hasPNr@prev(n, 1).
```

You should probably modify the way you do inserts as well. The feature in the compiler converting a "1" into a "Person", is called "refmode conversion". That feature is actually being removed because it often causes confusion (as it has already in your case :) ) So to insert without refmode conversion:

```
+Person(n), +Person:hasPnr(n, 1).
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is there any way that can delete all data once?  like delete all person in Person?

Comment: Sure. You can do: 

 -Person(n) <- Person@prev(n).